# How to iterate over json-schema structure in react?

Tags: json, reactjs, forms

I am new to react. I made a json structure for react to build the components. I do not care about the layout as I am assuming a vertical layout. 
For a simple form to be developed there are 8 components to be rendered from the json file as follows:

1. input box for name
2. input box for username
3. input box for email
4. input box for password
5. dropdown for country
6. radio button for gender
7. checkbox for language
8. submit button

The json file is as follows:

```
        {
"items": [
    {
        "componentType": "NameBox",
        "lable": "name",
        "properties": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 3,
            "desicription": "Enter Your Name"
        }
    },
    {
        "componenetType": "UserNameBox",
        "lable": "username",
        "properties": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 4,
            "maxLength": 8,
            "description": "Enter user name"
        }
    },
    {
        "componenetType": "EmailBox",
        "lable": "email",
        "properties": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^[a-z0-9]+(\\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,15})$",
            "description": "Enter email"
        }
    },
    {
        "componenetType": "PasswordBox",
        "lable": "password",
        "properties": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$",
            "description": "Enter password"
        }
    },
    {
        "componentType": "CountryDropDown",
        "lable": "country",
        "properties": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
                "AUS",
                "IN",
                "JP",
                "US",
                "RU",
                "Other"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "componenetType": "RadioButton",
        "lable": "gender",
        "properties": {

            "type": "string",
            "anyOf": [
                {
                    "type": "radios",
                    "key": "radios",
                    "enum": [
                        {
                            "value": "male",
                            "name": "Male"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "female",
                            "name": "Female"
                        }
                    ]
                }


            ]

        }
    },
    {
        "componenetType": "CheckBox",
        "lable": "language",
        "properties": {

            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                    "english",
                    "spanish",
                    "japanese",
                    "french",
                    "hindi"
                ]
            }
        }

    },
    {
        "componenetType": "SubmitButton",
        "lable": "Submit",
        "properties": {

            "type": "submit",
            "title": "Submit"
        }

     }
 ]
}
```

Now my question is how shall i iterate over this json file and get each component in the react? How shall I approach in react?

Comment: what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it seems just an array of objects.

The iteration on the array can be done with:

```
myjson.forEach(singleObject => {
  // my things here
})
```

Or, in case you need to map these objects to components in order to render them:

```
myjson.map(singleObject => {
  // return a rendered component here
})
```

I assume that you already have the components to render and to pass props down...

Answer (score 0):

Appending to **0xc14m1z** answer you need to use a map to iterate over the properties and render a form:

```js
class A extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const a = {
            "items": [
                {
                    "componentType": "NameBox",
                    "lable": "name",
                    "properties": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 3,
                        "description": "Enter Your Name"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "componenetType": "UserNameBox",
                    "lable": "username",
                    "properties": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 4,
                        "maxLength": 8,
                        "description": "Enter user name"
                    }
                },
            ]
        }

        return <div>
            {a.items.map(value => {
                return <div>
                    <h3>{value.lable}</h3><input type={value.properties.type} minLength={value.properties.minLength} maxLength={value.properties.maxLength} placeholder={value.properties.desicription} />
                </div>
            })}
        </div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<A />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```